# Any way to remove the git repository using python

Tags: python, linux, git, file

In my project I have used the **python-git** module to clone the repo.

> but for the cleanup I have to remove the directory as well.
> I am using the following method for cleanup but it did not work.

```py
def clone(self):
    if os.path.isdir(self.clone_dir):
        print("clone directory already exist.")
        print(f"Removing ... {self.clone_dir}")
        os.remove(self.clone_dir)
    try:
        Repo.clone_from(self.github_url, self.clone_dir)
    except Exception:
        raise Exception(f"Cant able to clone the repo {self.github_url}")
```

but this gives the error of - **self.clone_dir** is a directory

```bash
os.remove(self.clone_dir)
IsADirectoryError: \[Errno 21\] Is a directory: '/tmp/git/2bbf1c95-b981-4d7e-a000-9c25b8d84ffc'
```

> Any Efficient way to remove the git directory and well the UUID

tried -
list all the files then loop every file and then remove it.

Comment: [If `path` is a directory, an `OSError` is raised. **Use `rmdir()` to remove directories.**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)

Comment: os.rmdir give the directory not empty

Comment: Got it, now shutil.rmtree(self.clone_dir) worked for me.
Thanks